# How to incorporate 'public int' in actionPerformed button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

This is some ode that after declaring values in the fields.getText() it calculates a formula by a recursion function. However java does not see to like having any 'public' under actionPerformed button. I've never used one of these...but you do you think an ActionListener could do the job? Any ideas?

```
private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

         public int Method() { //underlined red
            int n = Integer.parseInt(objectsChooseField.getText());
            int r = Integer.parseInt(chooseFromField.getText());
            int result = C( n, r );
        }

        public int C( int n, int r ) { //underlined
            int res = faculty( n ) / ( faculty( r ) * ( n - r ));
            return res;
        }

        public int faculty( n ) { //underlined
            if ( n > 1 )
                return n * faculty( n - 1 );
            return 1;
        }

    }
```

EDIT:

I think I'm might have taken Joe's answer a little to literally...but do you mean something like this...?

```
public int Method() { //moved above actionPerformed

private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

                int n = Integer.parseInt(objectsChooseField.getText()); //continued method?
                int r = Integer.parseInt(chooseFromField.getText());
                int result = C( n, r );
            }
//rest of code below
```

Comment: You are trying to declare methods inside a method

Comment: As a side note, I think the function name you are looking for is `factorial`, not `faculty`...

Comment: Do you have a JavaScript background?

Comment: you can found [actionListener examples here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: @skuntsel nope sorry I don't have a JavaScript background, I'm a mere student learning the beginnings of java.

Comment: @user2344868 Ok, because nesting functions is legal there. In you case I would have started with [Oracle's online tutorial on using Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), which contains many examples of each component usage.

Comment: @user2344868, don't wrap the `actionPerformed` method inside your `method`. They're two different. What @Joe F wanted to said is that you should create the three methods you put inside your `actionPerformed` at the same level, then, inside your `actionPerformed` you could call them.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put methods inside of another method in Java. Move those 3 methods outside of, and at the same level as, `calculateButtonActionPerformed()`. You can then call them from within `calculateButtonActionPerformed()`.

For example, you can't do this in Java:

```
public void method1() {
    public void method2() {
    }
}
```

You have to do this:

```
public void method1() {
}

public void method2() {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've done a bit of an edit to show how I interpreted your answer, but I believe it's safe to say I've took it the wrong way.

Comment: @user2344868 You can't nest methods in Java. I've updated my answer to hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int method() { //your handlers
}
public int c(int n, int r) { //your handlers
}
public int faculty(int n) { //your handlers
}
public void calculateButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    method();
}
```

This is what Joe F explained in his answer. Try it this way.